# Use toast in successful axios request

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I want to add toast notification after successful axios response.
When I create a toast component and register it in vue
`app.component("ToastAlert", ToastAlert);`

How can I acctualy use it in this function?

```js
axios.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => {
     // want to use the toast notification here
     
     
     return response;
  },
  (error) => {
     // all 4xx/5xx responses will end here
     return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need take a look at :
https://raoulkramer.de/vue-js-axios-interceptors-and-toast-notifications/

in file define axios and interceptor add :

```
import Vue from 'vue';
```

and show toast

```
Vue.$toast.show();
```